# How to use GIT as document versioning system - muitiple concurrent users

Tags: git

I would like to manage versioning of some plain JSON text and GIT seems like a nice solution

We will have different users, connected to a single web application, each of them have their private "workspace**s**" information, which can be saved as JSON. I plan to give each workspaces an Id and each time user change and save something, it would be commited ( by triggering GIT command on server ) .

There will be a single GIT user and access control is managed by the web application only. I would like to ask if GIT is the right tool / production ready for this job. What should be done and what should be avoided with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Git is definitely a possible solution to your problem.  My recommendation is that you pretty-print your document such that each entry is one line, like so:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": [
         "x",
         "y",
         "z"
         ]
}
```

This will help reduce any conflicts in case you decide in the future that you'd like to merge multiple branches together.  Placing the document all on one line would result in merge conflicts if you tried to do a merge.

In addition, I recommend adding commits using libgit2 or one of its wrappers.  This means you don't need to worry about contention in the working tree, although you may still need to serialize accesses to update references.  It will likely be more performant as well, since you need not fork an additional process.

If your scenario doesn't require keeping old versions around, or doesn't need to keep every version forever, you may want to use a database instead of Git and store a few older versions if you need them.